# Build SharePoint project without SharePoint installed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I am working on an automated deployment POC for SharePoint projects. We are using jenkin jobs to download the source code from GIT repository and **BUILD** it where SharePoint is not installed and copy the WSPS to target SharePoint server for initiating deployment process using .ps1 files.

MSBuild is failing saying SharePoint related dlls are not available, which is expected. What is going to be the best way to supply the dlls? Or any better approach for this whole process?

The workaround what I'm thinking of at the moment is, I would adjust the jenkins job to download the source code from GIT to target SharePoint server directly and then build there rather than trying to build somewhere where SP is not installed and then move WSP to target SP Server. Please suggest.

Thanks is advance...

Comment: Did you find a solution? Is there no NuGet package for this yet?

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess the easy way would be to build on a SharePoint-Server. Share-Point installs many assemblies to the GAC and SharePoint-projects therefore depend on those being installed.

However, [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff622991.aspx) describes what is needed:

> [...] copy the following assemblies from the development system to the build
>   system and put them in a Reference Assembly folder:
>
> - Microsoft.SharePoint.dll
> - Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.dll
> - Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.dll
> - Microsoft.Office.Server.dll
> - Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll
> - Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
> - Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
> - Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime.dll
> - Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.dll
> - Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.dll
> - Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.dll
> - Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.dll
> - Microsoft.Office.SharePoint.Tools.dll
> - Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.dll
> - Microsoft.Web.CommandUI.dll
>
> These files are located in the following folder on the development system: 
>    `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI`
>
> It is recommended that you copy the SharePoint Server assemblies to the folder:
>    `.. \Program Files\Reference Assemblies\SharePoint\`
>
> And then add one of the following registry entries:
>
> - For 64-bit systems:
>     `HKEY_LOCAL_SYSTEM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Wow6432Node\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\SharePoint15]@="<AssemblyFolderLocation>"`
> - For 32-bit systems:
>     `HKEY_LOCAL_SYSTEM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\
>     v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\SharePoint15]@="<AssemblyFolderLocation>"`
>
> If your SharePoint Projects refer to other SharePoint Server assemblies, copy them to the build system as well.

so this might work...